# Logstash Docker on GCP Cloud Run: Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces

Tags: docker, logstash, google-cloud-run

I'm coupling PubSub with a Logstash custom image running on GCP Cloud Run, this image will output messages to an Elastic Cloud configuration.

I'm currently hitting some errors on Cloud Run which I can't seem to fix related to:
Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.9.0
ADD pipeline/ /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
ADD config/ /usr/share/logstash/config/
RUN bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-google_pubsub
RUN chown -R logstash:root /usr/share/logstash/config 
RUN ls -al /usr/share/logstash/config/
EXPOSE 5000
```

The config file looks like this:

```
input {

    google_pubsub {

        project_id => "${PROJECT_ID}"
        topic => "${PUBSUB_TOPIC}"
        subscription => "logstash-sub"
        create_subscription => false
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "${HOSTS}"
    user => "${USERNAME}" 
    password => "${PASSWORD}"  
    index => "${INDEX}"
    }
  stdout {
  }
}
```

If anyone helping with this requires any other data please let me know. I'm new to handling Logstash.

A little extra info on what I see happening:
The Container spins up fine, sets up a pipeline that already fetches the input from Pub/Sub, then after about a minute the aforementioned error comes up and I get a [logstash.runner ] SIGTERM received. Shutting down. message before the container deployment fails.

Comment: Could you also include on this post the complete build logs so we can see where the error started appearing?

Comment: were you able to solve the issue, I'm seeing the same issue, any help ?

Answer (score 1):

You're exposing Logstash container on port 5000. In [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port):

> The container must listen for requests on 0.0.0.0 on the port to which requests are sent. By default, requests are sent to 8080.
> Inside Cloud Run container instances, the value of the PORT environment variable always reflects the port to which requests are sent. It defaults to 8080.

However, you can [configure](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers) Cloud Run to send the requests to your preferred port (that is 5000). You can do this via `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud run services update SERVICE --port 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been having similar issues with GCR and I think I can provide a bit more background.  It turns out these are no ordinary containers.  Google has done a good job of obfuscating (more like castrating) the `/sys/` filesystem.  There is no `/sys/class/net/` directory listing the interfaces and no environment variable to guide you, but loopback won't be enough to satisfy port health requirements.  There are also no `/sys/devices/*/net/` directories.  So any attempt to run `ip a` or list IPs using standard tooling results in errors - usually ENOENT or no such file.

Some of our Golang services use standard go syntax for binding interfaces. Examples include "0.0.0.0:80" for all IPv4 on port 80, ":80" for all IPv4 and IPv6 on port 80, etc.  For some of our services that require you to bind to one interface, there seems to be no way to actually list the container's IP.

I can understand the reasoning behind hiding network details but then it would be good to at least have environment variables to find your expected IP internally for apps that are stubborn.

In the meantime anybody having a workaround for this is my hero.

[EDIT]
I found they haven't actually changed the `/proc` filesystem so you can actually `tail /proc/net/*` to find your network details.  Present are eth0 and eth1:

```
==> /proc/net/if_inet6 <==
fddf3978feb1d745000000000000c001 03 80 00 00 eth1
00000000000000000000000000000001 01 80 00 00 lo

==> /proc/net/tcp6 <==
sl local_address remote_address st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt uid timeout inode

==> /proc/net/udp <==
sl local_address rem_address st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt uid timeout inode ref pointer drops

==> /proc/net/udp6 <==
sl local_address remote_address st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt uid timeout inode

==> /proc/net/unix <==
Num RefCount Protocol Flags Type St Inode Path
```

Ergo I found I could explicitly bind with `fddf:3978:feb1:d745::c001`